# Why my Log Shipping not break due to LSN mismatch?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I configured log shipping from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2012 Server, secondary Server database recovery state is restoring and log shipping works good.
One day I take log backup manually through query ‘backup log db name to disk=’path.trn’
As per role if anyone take manual log backup, log shipping needs to break due to LSN mismatch but here my log shipping not break and its working good.
is this correct from lower SQL version to higher SQL version?

Comment: Please post your question to DBA site

Comment: So after taking log backup did you restored this log backup on 2012 server ?